# javacc for eclipse contains multiple errors

Tags: eclipse, javacc

Hi I have fairly acceptable knowledge in python and java and I have recently decided that to further progress in my  programming would be to creating my own language to use and manipulate when I needed to. I installed javacc plug-in for eclipse and have gone through some tutorials.

My problem is that when I create a new project (file> new > java project) and create a class in the "src" folder, everything I type into my workspace has an error. Eg:

STATIC = false;

"Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens"

Eclipse does this for everything except my class name, note there are no errors on my javacc template under projects.

Please help me find a solution or if an empty project should be compiled differently. Even an up to date tutorial on the very basics of this topic would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try starting with a new javacc template file.  Then at least you are starting with a file that has the correct syntax.  Use File > New > Other ... then select JavaCC > JavaCC Template File.  (I'm assuming the plugin you are using is the same as the one I am.)

Comment: JavaCC source files are named xxxxxx.jj. I suggest to use ant.

Comment: There is no need to use ANT. The JavaCC plugin will process the .jj file. Generally it does this each time the file is saved. Sometimes it needs to be explicitly invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the Eclipse [Java development user guide](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp), it should cover all the issues you may face at the start.

If it's not, please provide more information on what "javacc plugin" you have installed, and what code you actually try to compile.